# I can't understand the JWT Authentication well

Tags: authentication, token, jwt, http-token-authentication

Nowadays many developers use the JWT Authentication to authorize the api call.
By the way, if a hacker can capture the api call request of the authenticated user then he can have the authenticated JWT token. 
Then the hacker can access this api with the authorized JWT token, without his authenticating. 
Is this alright?
I am wondering that the JWT Authentication is actually safe.
Can you explain that?

Comment: And that is why you run all the traffic through an encrypted connection via HTTPS.

Comment: If we don't use the https, the JWT Authentication is unsafe?

Comment: Correct. JWT by it self is not secure. So it is up to the user to ensure the security of the token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A jwt is a code that contains information about the identity and claims of a user and is valid for only a limited amount of time.

The code cannot be read nor changed by anyone, except the authorization endpoint that issued the token. It is therefor *safe* in the sense that it cannot be tampered with. This means that the token can be *fully trusted*. You don't have to validate the token and you can use the identity information and claims without having to consult the database.

But this is also the disadvantage. Once issued the token is *valid until it expires*, since the expiration cannot be altered. That is why the token should only be send over a *secured line* to the server. You wouldn't want a hacker to intercept the token.

But if it happens, then what?

There are several options. You can use *short-lived* tokens, which means that a token expires short time after being issued. If a token was intercepted, it is only valid for a small amount of time. In that case you take for granted that a hacker can have access for limited time to the system. The advantage is that you need less resources and the effort of hacking is probably not worthwhile.

Another option is to *validate the token* on each request. This requires more resources (e.g. lookups in the database), though you can use some sort of caching. If something changes, like the ip address, then you can *invalidate* the token. But the question is if you can detect if a token was send by a hacker.

So it depends on the chosen strategy. *But*: if you issue a *long-lived* access token *without validation* (and thus without the possibility to revoke the token), then you'll have a problem if a hacker gets hold of an access token. So you'll need to do something to use it in a safe way.

While I think this should be enough to help you understand, I would like to mention the use of *refresh tokens*. If you use *short-lived* access tokens, then you may want to implement *long-lived* refresh tokens. These refresh tokens are meant to obtain a new access token after it expires. The advantage is that you don't need to send the credentials, the refesh token suffices. You can however only implement this in an *application that can keep a secret*. Because you most certainly do not want a hacker to intercept the (long-lived) refresh token.

Being used less frequently (opposed to the access token) you can add logic to validate the refresh token when used. You can consult the database and decide to reject the request (e.g. when ip address changed) and revoke the refresh token. In that case the user has to identify itself again (send credentials).

Answer (score 0):

JWT is just a secure msg transporter between fsb server and client so that fsb server can determine whether the client is logged in or not; if logged in, the fsb server will fetch personal unique user based data.

1. google oauth

   1. G sends back user gid to my server only if user has a google account and successfully inputs gmail and password correctly.
   2. user id is saved in jwt’s payload.
2. jwt

   3. if google validates the user and google returns gid
   4. create jwt content and internal maintenance: exp date, encryption
   5. jwt is sent and stored in local store of user’s browser;
   6. each user’s req sends jwt back to my server
   7. my server decodes the jwt using secretOrKey, which only my server has, and gets the content(uid) from the jwt.
   8. if uid is in my db, user had already registered and right now is logged in.
   9. send the requested data from my db to the user because he is logged in
   10. if use fails google validation due to wrong password or G email, jwt isn't created.
3. Process of JWT

   11. user’s google popup logs in
   12. google server returns information to my server. If the gid isn’t in my db, I’ll save it in my db so that the user can be registered.
   13. create jwt and add uid as content. Exp date.
   14. jwt is sent and stored in local storage of users browser
   15. user requests a page though http, it includes the jwt. my server checks whether this user is logged in or not by Login determination test: if user’s jwt uid is in my DB, user is logged in. the user requested data will be given to the user. If user doesn’t have jwt or uid doesn’t match then the user isn't logged in, send the user to login page.

JWT descriptions

1. https://medium.com/@rahulgolwalkar/pros-and-cons-in-using-jwt-json-web-tokens-196ac6d41fb4
2. https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-ins-and-outs-of-token-based-authentication
3. https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-anatomy-of-a-json-web-token
4. https://auth0.com/blog/cookies-vs-tokens-definitive-guide/

Comment: I didn't know how to organize the info properly which was taken from my notes